# Count number of nested elements using stream api java

Tags: java, java-8, count, java-stream

Count number of content using stream

```
class Subject {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private List<Unit> units;
}

class Unit {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private List<Topic> topics;
}

class Topic {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private List<Content> contents;
}

class Content {
  private String id;
  private String contentType;
  private SubTopic subtopic;
}
```

With Java 8 and Streams I want the count of the Content elements which is of contentType equal to the video.

To count topic I tried this:

```
int topicCount = subject.getUnits().stream()
    .map(Unit::getTopics)
    .filter(topics -> topics != null)
    .mapToInt(List::size)
    .sum();
```

Comment: are you really willing to check the `List` being `null`? when you wrote `.filter(topics -> topics != null)`? I mean I can read it, but you should avoid that. (assigning `null` to a `List`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use streams as below,

```
subject.getUnits()
        .stream()
        .map(Unit::getTopics)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(Topic::getContents)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(Content::getContentType)
        .filter("video"::equals)
        .count();
```

You can avoid map,

```
subject.getUnits()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e->e.getTopics().stream())
        .flatMap(e->e.getContents().stream())
        .map(Content::getContentType)
        .filter("video"::equals)
        .count();
```

Answer (score 4):

You could flat map the nested elements and count them:

```java
long videoContentCount = 
    subject.getUnits()
           .stream()
           .flatMap(u -> u.getTopics().stream())
           .flatMap(t -> t.getContents().stream())
           .filter(c -> c.getCountetType().equals("video"))
           .count();
```

Comment: `flatMap(Unit::getTopics)`, wouldn't that require `getTopics` to return a `Stream`?

Comment: @Naman arg, yes, I forgot to stream it, thanks for noticing! Edited and fixed.

Comment: Adding extra point for this. You could use `enum` for content type, instead of String literals for better type safety which would avoid NPE for `getContentType`